# What are the methods to solve differential equations with variable coefficients of the following form?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know some standard methods to solve ordinary differential equations of the form (mostly series solution methods):

$$\frac{dy^{n}}{dx^{n}}+a_1(x)\frac{d^{n-1}y}{dx^{n-1}}+...+a_{n}(x)y = 0$$

but none for the forms:

$$\frac{dy^{n}}{dx^{n}}+a_1(x)\frac{d^{n-1}y}{dx^{n-1}}+...+a_{n}(x)y = X(x)$$

Is it possible to convert the latter form to the former form? And/or what are the general techniques to solve differential equations of the second type?

Comment: See [Variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters), and, in the case of constant coefficients and $X(x)$ of some special form, [Method of undetermined coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients) or [Annihilator method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilator_method).